# Activity lifecycle - when activity exit with exception, does the whole application exit?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two activities in my Android application: MainActivity and Second Activity, in the SecondActivity have some code will cause the application FC, `"123".substring(10);` for example. In some device, when SecondActivity stops, the whole application exit, but in some device, only the SecondActivity is closed after the exception, MainActivity is still at the foreground.

When will the whole application exit, and when only the Activity which throws exception exit?

MainActivity

```
package com.niklaus.lifecycle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }});
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        System.out.println("Main Activity onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("Main Activity onResume");
    }
}
```

SecondActivity

```
package com.niklaus.lifecycle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Button btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                "123".substring(10);
            }});
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        System.out.println("Second Activity onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("Second Activity onResume");
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.niklaus.lifecycle"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.niklaus.lifecycle.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please be more specific, share your code and the specific Exceptions you receive.

Comment: Could you post your AndroidManifest file? Maybe about your tasks.

Comment: This problem maybe about task.